# Python Group by and Sum with a Blank space

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

[Revenue by Segment and Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49gQm.png)

I have a dataframe with Revenue by Segment and by Country. I want to get the Total Revenue by Country code. So I want the output to be:

```
Country  Revenue    
FR      26.38      
AE      12.02
```

This is what the data frame looks like now:

```
Country      Segment         Revenue    
FR           
         Digital Games        $2.40
         Music                $20.79
         Health and Fitness   $0.46
         Tech Enthusiasts     $2.73
AE     
         Digital Games        $9.99
         Games and Toys       $2.03
AT     
         Entertainment-Music  $0.09
AU
         Shopping             $52.45
         Auto Enthusiasts     $7.86
         Auto Owners          $25.92
         Culture and Arts     $8.04
         Higher Education     $25.81
         Digital Games        $2.60
         Games and Toys       $6.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your empty entries are `NaN`, if they are *not*, I advise you to make them `NaN`.  The general idea is to fill foward in your country column, then dropping null values, which places the country code next to each row that contains data, while removing the header row.  The `groupby` + `sum` is a simple operation from that point.

---

#### `ffill` + `dropna` + `groupby`

```
d = dict(
    Country=df.Country.ffill(),
    Revenue=df.Revenue.str.strip('$').astype(float)
)

df.assign(**d).dropna().groupby('Country')['Revenue'].sum()
```

```
Country
AE     12.02
AT      0.09
AU    128.80
FR     26.38
Name: Revenue, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!!